# Automatically detect to show allow permission after user deny in the first time asking

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I working with anroid app in Android M and need some permission that allow to access `CAMERA`, `RECORD_AUDIO`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, ... so I put my permission checking when user open the app in the first time. But if user deny it, how can I detect it automatically that user is using the feature that required permission then ask them again? Or I have to put my condition in every feature that need permission.

I know when we use some feature that required permission but not allowed already it will throw the exception, so do we have any class that handle this task?

Comment: Check whether permission is granted before accessing camera, record audio etc.

Comment: Override this onRequestPermissionsResult().

Comment: So if we don't have any class that auto run when user use feature that required permission, right??

Answer (score 1):

I use this logic: Every Activity extends a BaseActivity, in which there is a method that check the permissions everytime the onCreate() is called.

The method that I use is:

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, everytime the user launch a new Activity, the application check the permissions and display which permissions are not granted yet.

To manage the result, use `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

BTW, this logic will ask the user the permission even if the activity's feature doesn't require any permission.

If you want to ask the user the permissions only where the feature that requires a permission, you must check it in every activity

Answer (score 0):

onRequestPermissionsResult you can check particular Permission is granted or not you can call Permission dialog again from there if particular permission not granted for Example

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(permission_result)
        // Received permission result for camera permission.
        Log.i(TAG, "Received response for Camera permission request.");

        // Check if the only required permission has been granted
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
            Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission has now been granted. Showing preview.");
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_available_camera,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission was NOT granted.");
           // Ask again for permission
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(permission_result)

    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACTS) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received response for contact permissions request.");

        // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
        // checked.
        if (PermissionUtil.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {
            // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_available_contacts,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
           // Ask again for permission
        }

    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if we don't have any class that auto run when user use feature that required permission, right??

Comment: If you have such class that required those permission then initialize this class from onRequestPermissions on Grant

Comment: For example you have one service you use this for Contact reading then start service code write inside  if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         
        }